# How does this recurrence relation fit the algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I have the following pseudo code:

```
Multiply(y,z)    
1. if (z==0) return 0     
2. else if (z is odd)    
3.    then return (Multiply(2y, floor(z/2)) + y )    
4. else return (Multiply(2y, floor(z/2)))
```

Towards analysing this procedure's runtime, this recurrence relation is given as answer:

$\qquad \displaystyle T(z) = \begin{cases} 0 & z=0 \\ T(z/2)+1 & z>0\end{cases}$

Why is $T(z)=0$ when $z=0$? Shouldn't it be $1$ for this case?

And, the $+1$ in $T(z/2)\mathbf{+1}$ is because the worst case is 
`(multiply(2y, floor(z/2)) + y` (note the `+ y`). Am I correct?

Answer (score 4):

You should be careful about what is being counted. If you want to count "runtime" (as in, number of statements) the given recurrence is clearly wrong.

Reverse-engineering from the recurrence, it is probably supposed to count *additions*. In particular, note how the computation the parameters for recursive calls is ignored. I hope it is clear that the recurrence is correct for the worst-case then; your reasoning for $+1$ is spot-on.

Why does restricting your self to additions make sense here? Additions are one of the statements that are executed *most often* (in the worst case, that is ignoring line 4.). That means that the true runtime (in a theoretic model) is *proportional* to the number of additions. Since you are (most likely) after *asymptotics* in terms of $O$, counting additions is sufficient: the proportion-constant is lost in $O$, anyway.

You can, for the fun of it, set up a recurrence counting all statements. You'll see that the result has the same asymptotic growth as the one you were given.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bit of ambiguity in what you're looking for here.  I am going to assume it's the running time of the function.

I agree that it should be 1 when $z=0$ because it generally is considered to take $O(1)$ operations to return a function value.  However, this will only affect your final answer by an additive constant of 1.

The $+1$ factor in the recurrence $T(z) = T(z/2) + 1$ is caused by the overhead of calling the subfunction.

In other words, what happens at a given value of $z$ is:

The function is called (generally $O(1)$ work just to set up the stack, etc.)

The program tests whether $z$ is odd ($O(1)$ work)

The function calls itself with a smaller instance ($T(z/2)$ work), and then does an addition before returning ($O(1)$ work).

Add these up, and you get $T(z) = T(z/2) + O(1)$.  You can substitute $1$ instead of $O(1)$ in this case and you'll get the same answer so long as you're only worried about asymptotics.